# Extract contents from Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe "name" contains the names of people's first 10 job employers.

I want to retrieve all the names of employers that contain "foundation".

My purpose is to better understand the employers' names that contains "foundation".

Here is the code that I screwed up:

```
name=employ[['nameCurrentEmployer',
       'name2ndEmployer', 'name3thEmployer',
       'name4thEmployer', 'name5thEmployer',
       'name6thEmployer', 'name7thEmployer',
       'name8thEmployer', 'name9thEmployer',
       'name10thEmployer']]
print(name.loc[name.str.contains('foundation', case=False)][['Answer.nameCurrentEmployer',
       'Answer.nameEighthEmployer', 'Answer.nameFifthEmployer',
       'Answer.nameFourthEmployer', 'Answer.nameNinethEmployer',
       'Answer.nameSecondEmployer', 'Answer.nameSeventhEmployer',
       'Answer.nameSixthEmployer', 'Answer.nameTenthEmployer',
       'Answer.nameThirdEmployer']])
```

And the error is:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's you expected output

Comment: Try `name.loc[name['nameCurrentEmployer'].str.contains('foundation', case=False)]` instead of `name.loc[name.str.contains('foundation', case=False)]`. EDIt: pandas dataframe doesn't contain str, but a pandas series does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`, because `str` is an accessor of `Series` and not `DataFrame`.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#string-handling):

> `Series.str` can be used to access the values of the series as strings
>   and apply several methods to it. These can be accessed like
>   `Series.str.<function/property>`.

So if you have multiple columns like `["name6thEmployer", "name7thEmployer"]` and so on in your `DataFrame` called `name`, then the naivest way to approach it would be:

```py
columns = ["name6thEmployer", "name7thEmployer", ...]
for column in columns:
    # for example, if you just want to count them up
    print(name[name[column].str.contains("foundation")][column].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
foundation_serie=df['name'].str.contains('foundation', regex=True)   
print(df[foundation_serie.values])
```